# How to clone a User Profile?

Tags: windows, user-profiles

I have a Windows user profile all setup with all settings the way I want them. I want to copy the entire configured profile to a new user account.

How can I do that on Windows?

Comment: Inspired by [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100252/cant-clone-a-user-profile) Ubuntu question.

Comment: @techie007 this is not about Windows 7 specifically and I'm not using domains

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the [User State Migration Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722032%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to move profiles with their configurations.  It should pick up most of the configurations, but there is the possibility that some registry customizations made by 3rd party software might not get picked up.